# Using Option menu for non-physical buttons devices

Tags: android, options-menu

I am developing an application that must hide title bar to increase screen spaces and for design issues. on non-physical buttons devices like nexus-4 and for Android > 3.0, I can't switch to use Action bar because the title bar is hidden, and in the same times these devices hasn't physical buttons to use standard menu.
My Question: How can I solve this problem
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I solve this problem

Modify your UI to either:

- Add back the action bar, or
- Add something else on your screen, such as a button, to display something else on the screen that will serve as your "menu". You can see this approach used by many games.